# Google Pay hidden & its device admin

Tags: android-versions, google-apps, device-administrator, zte-blade

[image]

I cannot locate Google Pay on my Z971 ZTE phone in Apps, system, hidden, etc, however it is a device admin. If I attempt to click on it to remove it as an admin, the settings app immediately pops up a msg box - "settings has stopped". Trying to find an answer, I've attempted searches in FF & Duck but the results were rediculously unrelated.

Quite some time ago I stopped updating all google apps & disappointedly learned several apps cannot be; stopped, uninstalled or disabled!

Comment: Can you setup [tag:adb] in your PC, execute the command `adb shell dumpsys device_policy`, and then provide the output in the question by [edit]ing it?

Comment: Can you borrow one from somebody? We need to find out exactly whether Google Tez is indeed the device administrator or an impersonator app is installed? Also, can you browse into Play Store, search for Google Tez and see whether you get the option to install or open it? Also, try booting into [tag:safe-mode] and then try to remove that app from Device administrators. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'll post a scan from the Device Info app. after this response. As you can see, it found 2 instances each of Pay & locate, yet I cant locate them in apps & system. If I try to uncheck either Pay or Locate from Device Admin, Settings shuts down immediately. 

I did as you requested:
Zte Device Admin - not found
Google Tez - Install
Lookout - Open
Find my Device - Install
Google Pay - Install

Comment: Hello. Please use pastebin.com to upload the output data and then paste its link. It is hard to make sense of the data from the comments.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gS97QVXJ

Comment: Now instead of the 6 I now have 11 multiple instances. A new item, Screen Lock Service is new.

Comment: Firelord - any ideas?